# Is cyclohexol the same as cyclohexanol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, identification

I recently came across different names for the following compound:

[image: what is this]

Is the IUPAC name for this `cyclohexol` or `cyclohexanol`? Is the use of `cyclohexol` as seen in a [google patent](http://www.google.com/patents/CN1793099A?cl=en) and in [this Chinese thesis](http://www.globethesis.com/?t=1101360218458010) accurate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Note that I can only comment on the English translations!*

**Cyclohexanol** is correct, cyclohexol is just wrong. This is not the only error in the abstract of the thesis.

> Cyclohexone is the most [...]

isn't correct either. The name is **cyclohexanone**!